# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when run test with Junit 5

Tags: java, junit5

I created a simple test to try Junit 5:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void testJupiter() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

This is the dependency I use:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Stack trace is the next:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.loadTestEngines(ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.java:30)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.createListeners(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: Some more lines of the stack trace message would be helpful

Comment: Please share the import of the @Test annotation as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see that you are using IntelliJ which supports just specific versions of jUnit5.

[Junit5 - running tests in IntelliJ](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea)

Try e.g.

```
<version>5.0.0-M4</version>
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the dependency, did you also configure the JUnit5 plugin in your `pom.xml`? It should look like this (taken from [the docs](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven)):

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Comment: I tried to add the plugin. It helped only when I run mvn clean install. But if I right click on the test and then choose 'Run' it still failed with the same error. As it turned out the reason was in the specific dependency version for Intellij idea. but thanks any way!