# trying to run a test case via IntelliJ Idea, but I get java.lang.nosuchmethoderror

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I am trying to run this file, a test class I wrote for one of my classes.

when I try to run this via IntelliJ Idea, I get no `java.lang.nosuchmethoderror`, and it won't run the tests for me, it will find no test methods.

the errors are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.loadTestEngines(ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.java:30)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.createListeners(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

and this is my test class:
https://pastebin.com/FMTwu3Rd

I think there are some IntelliJ Idea setting errors, but I can't seem to find it. BTW the tests are run with JUnit 4.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have tried by doing clean and build?

Comment: this is not a IntelliJ issue, this is what happens if you pas the wrong type of argument, or call a method that doesn't exist

Comment: @BikramjitRajbongshi I am not sure how that works, I am new to IntelliJ Idea. can you maybe help?

Comment: not sure, but test methods without a test in it might indeed lead to trouble.     @Test
    public void getHighScoreTableTopX() throws Exception {
    }

Comment: Are you sure that the JUnit version is correct? `JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java` suggest JUnit 5 and not 4, and maybe that's the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003012/class-javalaunchhelper-is-implemented-in-two-places/43003231#43003231 view this

Comment: This is an IntelliJ IDEA issue. You resolve the issue by defining all the dependencies (Maven project). This question has been answered [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384624/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-when-run-test-with-junit-5).